# Passing Model to Web API results in null value

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

When I try to pass a value to my Web API using a Windows Forms Client like this:

```
SessionModel s = new SessionModel()
{
    SessionID = "123456"
};
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:49584/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", txtToken.Text.Trim());

try
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/account/depositaccounts", s);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();    // Throw if not a success code.

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Results", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
catch (HttpRequestException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
}
```

And the API Controller code is this:

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Authorize]
 [Route("DepositAccounts", Name = "DepositAccounts")]
 public HttpResponseMessage GetDepositAccounts(Models.AuthenticationBindingModel model)
 {            
     var sessionId = model.SessionID;
 }
```

When the model comes in the SessionID property is null. I confirmed that is not null on the client side.

When use Fiddler to create the Json request on the other hand it works. Am I missing something on the client side?

Thanks.

** EDIT: changed the property 'SessionId' to 'SessionID' on the client side. Same issue though.

Comment: You are sending a SessionModel and at API end accepting a Models.AuthenticationBindingModel! Are they compatible?

Comment: Do they have to be named the same? They have the same properties.

Comment: Just to eliminate it as a cause I renamed the class and ensured that the property 'SessionID' had the same capitalization. Also, to be more specific it's the SessionID property that is null NOT the model. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Change the API signiture to be `GetDepositAccounts(dynamic  model)` or use the same class on both client and server side.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently on the client side I was declaring my class with a constructor like this:

```
class SessionModel
{
    public SessionModel()
    {

    }

    public String SessionId { get; set; }
}
```

And it resulted in some extra data being added to the fields in the json request ('k__BackingField'). Although there are lots of articles on how to remove that from the response I couldn't figure out how to remove it from the request. Turns out declaring the class on the client side without the constructor removes that 'k__BackingField' text and then the request works.

```
class SessionModel
{
    public String SessionID { get; set; }
}
```

Not sure the reasoning behind this, just that it happens. If anyone wants to comment on the 'why' that would be great!